# Can't reach expected download throughput from S3 to m4.x16large instance

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I'm processing data with an m4.x16large instance using the Spark framework. I have to download many TB of data from S3 distributed in many files of ~128MB in size. According to the EC2 instance's specs, I should have up to 20Gbps of bandwidth throughput, this would translate to around ~2GB/s. However, when processing data from S3 I only achieve throughputs of ~650MB/s on average.

Both the instance and S3 bucket are in the same region and the machine's CPU load doesn't reach 100% so I'm assuming the bottleneck isn't processing speed. I am performing a lightweight aggregation on the data as it arrives and storing it in disk, but I don't see how this could limit the network throughput.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to get better performance when downloading data from S3? How can I better reach the theoretical limit of 20Gbps in network bandwidth?

**Edit:** I'm using the bare minimum to run this instance. I created a single public VPC with a subnet which has a service endpoint to S3.

From the VPC creation wizard I have:

> Public subnet instances use Elastic IPs or Public IPs to access the Internet.

Comment: How many concurrent/parallel downloads are you running when you achieve 650MB(b?)/s?  How does this instance access S3... Elastic IP? NAT Gateway?  NAT Instance?  S3 VPC Endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I added additional information to my question. Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide that might be helpful.

Comment: I don't see where you have explained how many parallel/concurrent downloads you are doing.  It would be helpful to know typical throughput you see on each individual download.

Comment: How can I get this info? When I try to read the data, Spark creates ~10k tasks corresponding to each of the files in the S3 directory. Since I have about 110 cores available, I assume this is the number of concurrent downloads? I read the data into a dataframe with `sparkSession.read.text(s3_path)`.